# How to catch click event with addEventListener

Tags: css, reactjs, modal-dialog

I am having a modal with button inside. Unfortunatly, it's not properly working. During the build I got an error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

Below is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
import '../../assets/styles/Login.css';

class LoginRegisterModal extends React.Component {  
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {show: false};
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      const signUpButton = document.getElementById('signUp');
      const signInButton = document.getElementById('signIn');
      const container = document.getElementById('container');

      signUpButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        container.classList.add('right-panel-active');
      });  

      signInButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        container.classList.remove('right-panel-active');
      });
    }

    ....
    render() { 

        const styleModal = {
            marginTop: "15%",
            marginLeft: "30%",
            padding: 0,
            width:770,
            height:480,
            backgroundColor:"#ffffffff",
            borderRadius:21.5,
        }

        return (         
        <Modal show={this.state.show} style={styleModal} > 
          <div class="container" id="container">
            <div>
            .....
            </div>
            <div class="overlay-container">
              <div class="overlay">
                <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
                    <h1>Sign in.</h1>
                    <p>
                      Nice to see you again.Login and continue the journey.
                    </p>
                    <button class="ghost" id="signIn">Sign In</button>
                </div>
                <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
                    <h1>Hey, new friend!</h1>
                    <p>New to the Village? Sign up and start your journey</p>
                    <button class="ghost" id="signUp">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Modal>
        );  
    }  
}  

export default LoginRegisterModal;
```

I have tried adding a if condition before the addListener but it's just fixing the error but not working.

Also I have tried to replace by onClick instead but it's not working the code

```
    signUpButton = () => {
        container.classList.add('right-panel-active');
    }
```

but container is not known..

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be inside component did mount method `componentDidMount()`. That's because when you look for a element with id "signUp" it doesn't exist yet. I don't encourage you to do what you are doing. A better approach would be `<button onClick={myMethod}>`

Comment: thanks. I will make try. I am probably having other issue because it's pur html/css code I am importing to React

Comment: Take a look at this: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Comment: Also, would be nice to use React State in your component to decide when to use certain css class or not. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#state-hook

Comment: thanks. But I do not understand how I could access to the `container` outside of the `render`

Comment: I try this :                     <button class="ghost" id="signUp" onClick={() => container.classList.add('right-panel-active')}>Sign Up</button>
but classList is generating an issue

Comment: Create ```componentDidMount()``` method and leave that code there: ```const styleModal = {
            marginTop: "15%",
            marginLeft: "30%",
            padding: 0,
            width:770,
            height:480,
            backgroundColor:"#ffffffff",
            borderRadius:21.5,
        }

        const signUpButton = document.getElementById('signUp');...```. Like I said, you are trying to get a element with ```document.getElementById('signUp')``` when it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215206/discussion-between-seb-and-iuri-brindeiro).